# Proving a matrix in invertible from the following question

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

The question says:

If matrix $A$ is invertible and $A + B = AB$, prove that matrix $B$ is invertible and $A^{-1} + B^{-1} = I$

Firstly, I was thinking that we can only prove that matrix $B$ is a square matrix because matrix $A$ is a square matrix. But I can't think of a way to prove that it's invertible as well.

For the rest of the question, can I write $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ as $(A + B)^{-1}$? I don't think it's correct.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: $A^{-1}(\color{blue}{A+B})B^{-1}=A^{-1}\color{blue}{AB}B^{-1}$

Comment: If $A$ is square, then $A + B$ is only defined if $B$ is square and of the same size

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Hello and thanks for your answer. Understood! Could you also let me know how I can prove that $B$ is invertible?

Answer (score 2):

First we use the equation given as

$$A^{-1}(A+B)=A^{-1}AB$$

which implies
$$I+A^{-1}B=B.$$

Then to find the inverse of $B$ we start by assuming that $B$ is invertible which leads to

$$(I+A^{-1}B)B^{-1}=BB^{-1}=I.$$

This gives

$$B^{-1}+A^{-1}=I$$

and then we can write $$B^{-1}=I-A^{-1}$$ which we can check satisfies:

$$(I-A^{-1})B=B-A^{-1}B=I$$

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. So, how can I prove that $B$ is invertible beforehand?

Comment: @JOUA you can see that B is invertible by using $I-A^{-1}$ to act on $B$. This will give you $B-A^{-1}B$ which then using the second equation in my answer, i.e. $I+A^{-1}B=B$ rearranges to $B-A^{-1}B=I$ and hence $B^{-1}=I-A^{-1}$